# Getting texbox value in PHP script

Tags: javascript, php

I have a textbox in a webpage into which the user can enter text, they can then click "Preview" to generate and open a PDF containing that text in a new browser window. The code I currently have is:

```
function tryPDF() {
 var timestamp = +new Date;
 var win = window.open("postsurvey.php"
  + "?content=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("pdfinfo").value)
  + "&aspdf=true"
  + "&preview=true"
  + "&t=" + timestamp, "_blank");
 win.focus();
}
```

Further down the page is the textbox;

```
<div class='use' style='font-weight: normal; padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;' onclick='tryPDF()'>PREVIEW</div>
<textarea id='pdfinfo' style='font-family: Courier New; font-size: 10pt;
width: 99%;' rows=8 spellcheck='false'></textarea>
```

This works fine - up to a point - the point being when a large amount of text is entered and it's too much to pass.

Is there a way I can reference the textarea from the `postsurvey.php` script?

Comment: textareas don't have values. `.val()` would work,b ecause jquery will just grab the textarea's .innerHTML for it, but `.value` doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm ok, well it works somehow! Just need to do it differently so it works for larger amounts of text...

Comment: I think the problem here is your trying to append a potentially very long string to a url.  Url have a somewhat limited length.  (Google "Url length limit").  You could alter your code to send the data in a POST request, then in your success call back open the new window.  This would require some leg work server side, but nothing usually difficult.